# Does `fd-find` have an internal max-depth?

Tags: shell, files, find, fd

I have a bunch of files named like `fn._mm*` in a subdirectory:

```
...
./homedots/vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/rust-analyzer/share/doc/rust/html/core/core_arch/x86_64/avx512f/fn._mm_cvttss_i64.html
./homedots/vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/rust-analyzer/share/doc/rust/html/core/core_arch/x86_64/avx512f/fn._mm_cvtt_roundsd_i64.html
./homedots/vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/rust-analyzer/share/doc/rust/html/core/core_arch/x86_64/avx512f/fn._mm_cvt_roundss_i64.html
./homedots/vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/rust-analyzer/share/doc/rust/html/core/core_arch/x86_64/avx512f/fn._mm_cvtt_roundss_i64.html
./homedots/vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/rust-analyzer/share/doc/rust/html/core/core_arch/x86_64/avx512f/fn._mm_cvtsd_i64.html
./homedots/vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/rust-analyzer/share/doc/rust/html/core/core_arch/x86_64/avx512f/fn._mm_cvttsd_i64.html
./homedots/vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/rust-analyzer/share/doc/rust/html/core/core_arch/x86_64/avx512f/fn._mm_cvt_roundsd_i64.html
...
```

If I look for those files using `find -iname "fn._mm*"`, I can find them without problems, in fact that's how I've printed the above lines.

but when using `fd-find`:

```
fd fn._mm
```

or

```
fd "fn._mm"
```

yields nothing. Even when using the `--glob` switch and an asterisk (`*`) at the end of my pattern, it yields nothing.

**However**, if I go a couple directories deeper (in the above example I'd have to `cd` into `homedots/vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/rust-analyzer`), I can now find the files I'm looking for with `fd-find`:

```
fd "fn._mm"
...
share/doc/rust/html/core/core_arch/x86_64/avx512f/fn._mm_cvttss_i64.html
share/doc/rust/html/core/core_arch/x86_64/avx512f/fn._mm_cvtt_roundsd_i64.html
share/doc/rust/html/core/core_arch/x86_64/avx512f/fn._mm_cvt_roundss_i64.html
share/doc/rust/html/core/core_arch/x86_64/avx512f/fn._mm_cvtt_roundss_i64.html
share/doc/rust/html/core/core_arch/x86_64/avx512f/fn._mm_cvtsd_i64.html
share/doc/rust/html/core/core_arch/x86_64/avx512f/fn._mm_cvttsd_i64.html
share/doc/rust/html/core/core_arch/x86_64/avx512f/fn._mm_cvt_roundsd_i64.html
...
```

`--max-depth` is unset in `fd-find`, and there are no symlinks in between (I've still checked with the `-L` switch to be sure, though).

Is there a bug, or is there some other limitation I'm missing?

For now, the solution is to simply use `find` and `fd-find`, when I'm unsure, however I prefer using `fd-find`.

Comment: Does `fd -I fn._mm` find the files?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I'll check as soon as I'm back home. How can the restrictions be of a problem though? And is there some sort of caching in between perhaps? I was thinking perhaps I need to clear some `fd-find` cache or something...

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski it did! It seems there are some sort of `.gitignore` files in some of the subdirs that are filtering `fd`. Is this `fd`'s standard behavior? If it is, I'd need to turn it off, as it is quite annoying to me. I suppose some sort of `.fdrc` is possible?

Comment: I really don't know. My experience with `fd-find` is: I read your question, I skimmed through the manual. That's all. Now it's your turn to skim through the manual. :)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski it's fine. I was expecting `fd` to be "very similar" to `find`, didn't expect it to have said "feature", and really presumed it to be either my mistake or some sort of error. Thanks for your help!